# when in Rails irb, how to traverse to beginning/end of line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when in Rails irb, how to traverse to beginning/end of line?

is it possible to fire up 'irb' and have it automatically require some libs?

Comment: The second question doesn't seem related to the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move to the beginning/end of a line, you can use Ctrl-A/Ctrl-E or Home/End.

You can place arbitrary Ruby code in `~/.irbrc`.